# Using asp.net resx to control different strings but not different languages

Tags: c#, asp.net, resx

Generally I use resx to control language, a system in 2,3 different languages and it is OK. However, imagine I have only one language and 3 different companies using my system. Two of these companies use the word outsourced to define people who works to them and the other one uses the word collaborator.  I was wondering if it is possible to make a label text be shown as Outsourced if it is from company x and y and Collaborator if it is from company z. Can I use resx to control it?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add a resource file to the App_GlobalResources folder, then in your code call GetGlobalResourceObject("MyResourceName", "MyResourceKey");

eg:

return (String)GetGlobalResourceObject(ResourceName, Key);